Guest User data not stored in quote 2.4.7
We have recently installed the 2.4.7-p1 and facing an issue with guest abondand. While we were debugging we found the guest user data like email, name, etc not stored in the quote table even in the quoted address. If anyone faces the same issue then please provide the solution.

Hey, can you please once try disabled all third party modules and check.
